# Where should we do async Api call in Redux ,when you are using React-hooks?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am new to React Hooks. I have doubt when you need to do any API call
in Redux using Hooks how should you write async API calling function. Should it be a local function? Or It should follow the same pattern as we do in React-Redux.

Comment: Depends on how and if you store data result in state. You can use the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook to dispatch an action to fetch data if the data is missing. If you have many components that may request data then you can create a grouping object in container to group requests from components into one request.

Comment: you can call the api in useEffect and pass the state variable or props variable which is going to be change, so when the passed one in second argument of array changes only it will call again

Comment: Suppose there are several components . All components need to do one API call respectively.So is it still a good way to do the API call in useEffect of the respective component or Like we normally do in Redux async API operation using redux-thunk we have something for hooks as well.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different technologies exists, that may be confused.

1. Redux with [hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks).

   They are part of React-redux library (`connect` function is also part of it). In this case, hooks like `useDispatch` is just the same as using `connect` with second argument set to `null`. `dispatch` function will be made available to the component and you can dispatch plain object actions (like `{ type: ACTION1, payload: 'payload' }` or async actions (functions) if you've used thunk middleware when creating store.

   So in this case hooks are just another way to access the same Redux store
2. React hook [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer). This is not relate to Redux at all. To use `useReducer` you are not have to add Redux to project. `useReducer` is provided by React itself and has lot of limitations compared to Redux. Here are some:

   a. There is no way to use middleware. All async actions should be processed using `useEffect` or similar technologies.

   b. It cannot be used with any of React-redux functions. So you have to establish context or pass `dispatch` function using `props` to children

   `useReducer` can be considered as very simplified version of Redux

Answer (score 0):

You can use useEffect hook. Below is an example:

```
const todo = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        <api calls>
    }, [ <value to be watched> ] );       
}
```

Whenever value to be watched changes, the first argument (i.e. arrow function above) gets executed.

Let's say you want the api calls to get executed only once, in that case keep values to be watched as empty. And you are good to go.